# DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader relative?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, asp.net-mvc-2, fancybox

ASP.Net MVC is throwing errors like mad when using fancybox in Internet Explorer

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
    src='fancybox/fancy_title_over.png', 
    sizingMethod='scale');
```

Are `DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader` src paths relative like all other css paths?

Comment: @Darin, I realize that this has nothing to do with `fancybox` or `ASP.NET MVC` but I thought I would tag this question with those since that's what I'm using and maybe someone has a clever workaround for those technologies.

Comment: that's pure CSS, nothing to do with MVC.

Comment: @Darin, like I said, I realize this fact

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add an extra `/` at the beginning of your `src`:

`src='/fancybox/fancy_title_over.png'`

If that doesn't work you may need to use an absolute URL.

> ColorBox's borders do not display in Internet Explorer:
>
> Some of the example styles provided
>   make use of transparent .PNG files.
>   Alpha transparencies aren't supported
>   by default in IE6, and can cause an
>   undesirable 'black halo' effect in IE7
>   and IE8 when changing their opacity.
>   ColorBox resolves this by using one of
>   IE's CSS filters. You can see these at
>   the bottom of colorbox.css. The filter
>   src paths are relative to the HTML
>   document (just like an IMG element),
>   while CSS background image paths are
>   relative to the CSS document. In the
>   examples I provide the relative path
>   is the same, but users often change
>   the directory structure once they move
>   the files over to their own host. The
>   filter src path needs to reflect this
>   change with the appropriate relative
>   path or an absolute path. Here is an
>   example that assumes the 'images'
>   folder is in the root directory:
>
> Original CSS with incorrect relative
>   path:
>   .AlphaImageLoader(src=images/internet_explorer/borderTopLeft.png
>
> Corrected relative path:
>   .AlphaImageLoader(src=/images/internet_explorer/borderTopLeft.png
>
> Corrected absolute path:
>   .AlphaImageLoader(src=http://your_domain.com/images/internet_explorer/borderTopLeft.png

**[Source](http://drupal.org/node/841932)**

Comment: Weird, this doesn't seem to work for me...my IE7 browser is trying to load "/Content/fancybox-1-3-4/fancy_shadow_n.png" instead of a relative path from my application root. The real path should be MyAppRoot/Content/fancybox-1-3-4/fancy_shadow_n.png. Any ideas? This is my entry in jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css: ".fancybox-ie #fancybox-bg-ne { filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='/Content/fancybox-1-3-4/fancy_shadow_n.png', sizingMethod='scale'); }
"

Comment: in my case only adding a relative path to 'Content' (/content/themes/themename/js/fancybox/fancy_title_over.png) solved the issue. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I removed completely IE section that uses filter, and it improved tremedously the load and reduced the response time on each page rendering. take a reference at this

http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#no_filters